# Problems with “Pause Until Date” activity in SPD-created workflows

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow and I'm trying to send an email when an item is added or updated from a calendar list. I tried using the Pause Until Date activity as I need to send the email 2 days before the due date but it just pauses and never fires. Any ideas why it isn't firing as expected?

Answer (score 3):

This is known issue in 2007 version. Here you have hotfix

[A Microsoft Windows Workflow Foundation timer does not resume correctly after reloading a workflow.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21066)

> Overview
>
> In Microsoft Windows Workflow Foundation, a timer does not
>   resume correctly after reloading a workflow.
>
> This fix will resume execution for all delayed workflows with
>   satisfied conditions.

Comment: I tried downloading the patch but it gave me an error. I have SP 2010, does that matter?

Comment: @TimTang: This patch is for 2007 version. I am not sure if this is still a issue in 2010.