# e-mail not firing after the second pause until

Tags: workflow

[image: Share Point Workflow]

**I have defined the above workflow in Sharepoint 2007**

Late Date is set by the workflow to be 1 day later than the due date (currently it is set to 5 minutes for testing purposes).  It is the field that is used to trigger when the late notification is sent out.

Date Counter is a field that is updated by the workflow to monitor the passage of time. On initial creation Date Counter is set to Create Date.  On modification, Date Counter is set to modified date.  The workflow compares Date Counter to the Due Date.  If it Date Counter is less than Due Date, the workflow then sets it to the Due Date and pauses until due date.  If the Date Counter is equal to the due date and status is not complete, it sends an email indicating the task is due.  If the due date counter is greater than or equal to the late date and the task isn’t complete, it sends a notice the task is late.

***When run, I get the first e-mail when due date is reached and also the second e-mail when late date is reached. But subsequent e-mails which must be sent evry 5 mins is not being sent. (The late date and date counter are incremented by 5 mins. each time). NOT SURE WHY***

Comment: Might be related to this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/19130

Comment: I can't see an email action step, have you omitted this or is it in another block? How are the emails being sent out?

Answer (score 0):

When you get into the "Else If" clause, you start by adding 5 minutes to "date counter adjuster".  However, I don't see if/what this value begins at.  If you're coming into this workflow "on modified" for a new start, for instance, that variable is...blank?  Is it possible that variable starts at the Created Date or something?  So adding 5 minutes just leaves it at 5 minutes after create and not what you intended, which is I'm assuming 5 minutes after Late Date?  I'm wondering if you need to begin that ElseIf by setting that variable to LateDate?

Next, in your update item within ElseIf, am I correct that you're updating Late Date to that variable?  Or to Late Date + 5 min?  I can't see what's updated there...

Finally, once it pauses until Late Date, I assume the Workflow wakes up from that point and runs through to the end.  But is there anything that would trigger it to run again, come back to your ElseIf statements from the top, and do the emails again?  It seems like you're expecting it to loop here or something.